# Best SQL schema for checkboxes with "other" option

Tags: sql, postgresql

I will have an HTML form that is a list of predefined checkboxes with an option to enter an "other" string if the option you're looking for isn't in the checkboxes. Note that you can check 0 or many checkboxes.

Let's say we're talking about a `User` selecting `Institutions` such as "school", "preschool", "daycare", ect.

What would be the best schema to store this in a relational database? (PostgreSQL if that makes any difference)

I was thinking about two options:

1. `User` has a one-to-many relationship with the `institutions` table in which I insert every one of their choices + the "other" string if not null.
2. `User` has a many-to-many relationship with the `institutions` table that is populated with my default choices. `User` also has an `institutionOther` field in which I store the "other" string.

Which is the best? Is there anything else I should be doing instead?

Comment: This depends on how the reporting for your users works. I would tend towards the first option and add a `note` column or similar to the `institutions` table. You can then `insert` the `non-null` string from 'other' and have the option to capture more info about each of the institutions a user has selected in the future. The reason for creating a separate field for the 'other' is so that you will have a predictable field (probably something like `institutions.type`) to search on in the future.

Comment: Apart from the static picture, it might be helpful to ask yourself how the queries would look. If a frequent query is overly complicated or inefficient, that's a point against the data model.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would consider a third option: a User table, an Institutions table, a UserInstitutionsOther table and a UserInstitutions table. The structure would be like this:

```
Users  
  UserId PK
  (other fields containing user information)

Institutions
  InstitutionId PK
  (string field containing "default" institution description)

UserInstitutions
  UserInstitutionId PK
  UserId FK
  InstitutionId FK

InstitutionsOther
  InstitutionsOtherId PK
  UserId FK
  (string field to contain value)
```

UserInstitutions is the associative entity that resolves the many-to-many relationship between users and institutions. InstitutionsOther contains any records where the user has entered "other."

This structure avoids some economy issues that your options have. Your first option (if I understand your description correctly) requires that all of your institutions be entered as strings, to accommodate the "other" string. That requires more space than a foreign key ID, and creates problems down the line if you want to, say, fix a misspelling in an institution name. The second option is an improvement, but if you have the "other" field in the Institutions table, you're going to have mostly null values in that column. Further, you'll have a null value in the foreign key column for the "regular" institutions whenever there's an "other" value.

Using this structure, you'll have all of your "regular" institutions in one table, where you can edit the strings as necessary, and add new institutions easily. If you have an "other" entry, you simply don't have a value for it in UserInstutions, and you do have one in InstitutionsOther. All of the tables are properly related, and all of the fields can be constrained to prevent null values.

One point about querying this schema. If you are, say, getting a list of all the users and all of the institutions they have selected, you'll need to do a `LEFT JOIN` between Users and UserInstitutions and between Users and InstitutionsOther. If you do an `INNER JOIN`, you won't get any users who haven't selected both at least one "regular" institution and an "other" institution; in other words, a selected user record would have to have a corresponding record in both UserInstitutions and InstitutionsOther.